# Where can I find a Windows 10 driver for old Syquest Drives?

Tags: hard-disk, driver

SyQuest made portable hard drive diskettes. I believe they have been out of business going on a couple of decades. At any rate I have some disks and the hardware, but I am unable to find drivers. I would really like to get at the data I have on these disks (Some old pictures). Unfortunately I keep hitting dead ends trying to find drivers.

So were can I find drivers for a modern Windows OS, or what could be other alternatives?

Comment: Would running an older OS (one for which drivers are available) in a virtual machine be an option? You could then get the files into the virtual machine, and then grab the files from the VM (most VM hypervisors will allow you to "mount" the virtual disk image in a modern OS and access the files).

Comment: There was a web site maintained for awhile with drivers, (It is referenced on the SyQuest Wiki page) However last I looked there was nothing there.

Comment: Many SyQuest drives were SCSI or IDE, which should make them pretty much plug and play with Windows 10 and most other OSes. The parallel port version would require a driver. If you have that version, it may be easier to acquire a SCSI or IDE version that takes the same cartridge type.

Comment: I have a SyQuest drive in my Windows 98 box, and it is indeed a SCSI connection.  If your drive is SCSI, then the only drivers required for windows should be the drivers for your SCSI card, not the SyJet.  I suspect the same holds true for IDE (if they made an IDE version?).  I don't think newer boxes even _have_ a parallel port anymore, so that is going to be more problematic.

Comment: To add to @Geo's comment: and you can't use a USB-to-Parallel-Port adapter, since the translation between USB and parallel doesn't work that way.

Comment: You can easily add a PCI parallel port card to modern PCs though, if that turns out to be what you need to hook it up.

Comment: You need to find the adapted the drive uses and look for drivers for that.

Comment: As you say, i understand that you are not trying to use this drive on windows 10, you are only interested in retrieving data on old disks. If this is true, I strongly suggest that you put the model of your drive , it will help a lot. Also, a driver _specifically_ made for Windows 10 may be not needed at all, depending on the interface of your device. I suggest that you change your question to something like "How to read data from Seaquest model xxxx on a laptop/desktop with Windows 10".

Comment: (Continuation )If however you really need to read _and_ write to those disks, then things get really more complex, and a virtualization solution will probably be mandatory.

Comment: @Jon have you looked at the non working link provided on the Syquest Wiki though the archive.org wayback machine? Also to reiterate the comment  from flavio can you post a picture of the drive you have so that this question can be answered and not just have a pile of comments on it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Not anywhere related to Retrocomputing.

Comment: @Raffzahn I could of swore this question was in the original proposal for retrocomputing and that it scored ten+. But I can't find it. Anyway the HD in question has been out of production for decades. So I am having a hard time understanding why you think this should be closed. Could you elaborate more? Be a little more specific?

Comment: @Jon It would be great to see that reference. For one, I would not considere RC as the support for no longer sold products in general, but more important, the problem described isn't related to the hardware, but todays software. It's asking for help in Windows 10, which is most definitly not on topic.

Comment: @jon Also, I could just add one reason for closing, but there's another equaly important. The question *contains no information about the drive or media* where a solution is asked for. Syquest produced more than 15 different drives in many different packages with 10+ different media in at least 4 sizes (2,5";3,5";3,9";5,25") that would fit the description. So any anser would be pure guessing, which is not what stackexchange is about.

Comment: I can’t find any similar question in the [site definition](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94441?phase=definition). However, I do think this is on-topic for RC (it would be better as “How can I read old SyQuest disks using a SyQuest drive on a modern system?”), although as @Raffzahn says, it would merit clarification. We have other similar questions on the site...

Answer (score 6):

Your best bet to rescue this data, in my opinion, will be to use the Linux operating system.  It supports older hardware extremely well compared to most operating systems.

If you know what you are doing, you can install Linux on a Windows system and select which operating system to use at boot, and there are also live DVDs (which can also be installed on flash drives) which you can use to boot a temporary Linux system.

Once in Linux, you'll read the data and move it to another device - for example, a USB flash drive (separate from the boot flash drive if you used one to boot Linux) - and then read that device when you boot back into Windows.